# Heroku syncdb fails because of easy_thumbnail

Tags: django, heroku-toolbelt, easy-thumbnails

I get the same error everytime I try to deploy my app using Heroku

```
'ImportError: No module named easy_thumbnails.optimize'
```

My app was running just fine locally on Django but since I moved it to deploy it on heroku I am getting this error

My github can be found at https://github.com/henrigeek/Django

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a requirements.txt file, so Heroku cannot install your dependencies, which presumably include easy_thumbnails as well as Django.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`